# How can I create a dynamic delegate in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to create a view using `ListView`, where each row will have `Rectangle` elements defined by a model. Each element of the model represents a row, but these elements may have more than one `Rectangle` to draw, defined in a role with an array named *blocs*.

I don't know how to define the delegate to create the number of `Rectangles` defined in the model for each row of the `ListView`. I want each bloc to be independent from the others, so in the future I can make them draggable and resizeable.

This is my **BlocModel.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

ListModel {

    ListElement{
        blocs: [
            ListElement{
                OriginX: 100
                length: 100
                color: "blue"
            },
            ListElement{
                OriginX: 300
                length: 75
                color: "green"
            }
        ]
    }
    ListElement{
        blocs: [
            ListElement{
                OriginX: 0
                length: 50
                color: "red"
            },
            ListElement{
                OriginX: 100
                length: 75
                color: "yellow"
            }
            ,
            ListElement{
                OriginX: 300
                length: 100
                color: "blue"
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

This is the **main.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 500
    visible: true

    ListView {
        id: blocsListView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: BlocModel {}
        delegate: BlocDelegate {}
    }
}
```

And this the BlocDelegate.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

ItemDelegate{
    id: root
    width: parent.width
    height: 50

    //each row
    Rectangle{
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "gray"

        //What should I add here to make the following element repeat according to the number of elements in the array "blocs"? 
        //each bloc should have the following delegate
       /* Rectangle {
            id: bloc
            x: OriginX
            width: length
            height: parent.height
            color: model.color
        }*/
    }
}
```

How can I make my delegate dynamic? Can I use somehow a Javascript `for` loop or should I use a C++ model and add the blocs from there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution that may fit your requirement if all your delegate items are the same type(In this case only rectangle). If you are having delegate items of different types (Rectangle, Item, Button, RadioButton) you have to load the predefined items with matching types into a loader.

```
=========BlocDelegate.qml=======
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Column {
    width: parent.width

    Repeater {
        model: blocs
        delegate: Rectangle {
            height: 40
            width: parent.width
            color: rectcolor
        }
    }
}


========BlocModel.qml========
import QtQuick 2.0

ListModel {
    ListElement {
        blocs: [
            ListElement {
                rectcolor: "lightgreen"
            },
            ListElement {
                rectcolor: "skyblue"
            },
            ListElement {
                rectcolor: "orange"
            }

        ]
    }
    ListElement {
        blocs: [
            ListElement {
                rectcolor: "yellow"
            },
            ListElement {
                rectcolor: "steelblue"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```